# How do I create dual-coloured rings in CSS?

Tags: html, jquery, css, opencart2.x, php-7.4

How do I do the rings in this design in `CSS` and/or `JS`?

[image: icons]

The number of icons is dynamic.

- First icon is all grey
- Icons in-between a mix of grey and blue
- Last icon is a blue gradient

It is a requirement for the rings to be dynamic; not part of the image.

Comment: All the blue part rings look as though they are gradients not just the last one, is that true (makes a general solution easier),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create pseudo-element (:before) in the background with extra height and width than the actual element. Then use `conic-gradient` as background for that pseudo element.

Check the below example:

```css
.knob {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.knob:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: conic-gradient(#006, #00f 25%, #888 0);
    transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<div class="knob">25%</div>
```

For customization options, check the below CodePen link.

https://codepen.io/rohitutekar/pen/BadOgmg

Answer (score 1):

Using conic, radial and linear gradients and a pseudo element you can build up the elements as in this snippet.

The percentage of 'completion' that an element is to show can be set (via JS or PHP or whatever you are using) by setting a CSS property (variable) which is called --pc in this snippet.

CSS can then calculate the degrees required for a conic gradient to get the required portion of the 'ring' overwritten.

The icon in the middle can be introduced via CSS mask property and with a linear-gradient background it will take on the same gradient colors as correspond in the ring.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
}

.partCircle {
  position: relative;
  --lighterBlue: #3490ef;
  --darkerBlue: #304088;
  --gray: #484848;
  --deg: calc(360 * (100 - var(--pc)) / 100);
  --seg: calc((360 - var(--deg)) * 1deg);
  height: 6vw;
  width: 6vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 0 65%, transparent 65% 100%), conic-gradient(transparent 0 var(--seg), var(--gray) var(--seg) 360deg), conic-gradient(var(--lighterBlue) 0deg, var(--darkerBlue) 180deg, var(--lighterBlue) 360deg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.partCircle::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--lighterBlue), var(--darkerBlue));
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-image: var(--icon);
  mask-size: 60%;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
  -webkit-mask-image: var(--icon);
  -webkit-mask-size: 60%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="partCircle" style="--pc: 25; --icon: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);"></div>
  <div class="partCircle" style="--pc: 50; --icon: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);"></div>
  <div class="partCircle" style="--pc: 62.5; --icon: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);"></div>
  <div class="partCircle" style="--pc: 75; --icon: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);"></div>
  <div class="partCircle" style="--pc: 87.5; --icon: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);"></div>
  <div class="partCircle" style="--pc: 100; --icon: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg);"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use border-image

```
border-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, darkorchid) 1;
```

see the below example.

```css
.btn-gradient-1 {
  background-color:transparent;
  border-width: 4px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkblue, darkorchid) 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding-x-md padding-y-xl flex flex-center">
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="margin-bottom-xs">
      <button class="reset btn-gradient-1">Button One</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: in your case you might like to give the button same height and width with `border-radius:50%` to make it round.

i hope this was helpful.

Comment: Where's the grey part of the border?

Comment: @DavinaLeong i set colors as darkblue, darkorchid on border-image you can set it to grey and blue as per your requirement